# Socket.IO and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is my NodeJS server:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user connected to the chat!');

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

And here is my client:

```
var socket = io();
socket.connect('http://server:1337', { autoConnect: true});
socket.on('connect',function() {
  socket.emit('chat message', "TEST");
});
```

And on my client side I get the following error in the console:

> Cannot GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LOIMkAR

Comment: The socket should be connected after the call to `var socket = io();`. Do not call `connect`.

Comment: How can I connect to a custom ip then ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `var socket = io.connect()`, it will try to connect to the server automatically.

Unless you want to connect to a custom IP, which don't make much sense. `io.connect()` will do what you want to do.

After that you will use `socket.emit` for emitting events and `socket.on` for listening to events.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working with this setup similar to [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```